# JavaScript curly braces with no function or json

Tags: javascript

Just opened a client's javascript file and the first lines are along the lines of this:

```
{
    var s_account="blog";
}
```

Which I don't get.  Normally, in my experience, curly braces wrap around a function...

```
function welcome(){ ...
```

...or a <del>json</del> *JavaScript* object

```
var attributes = { this : "that...
```

Can anyone tell me why there are curly braces with no text before them or after them? What does it do / what is the point of it?

Comment: You can wrap block of codes with curly braces, without the need of a variable or function.

Comment: Yeah, you clearly can as the script runs... I'm just curious as to why its written like that - what does it achieve?

Comment: That's not a "JSON object", it's a "JavaScript object".

Comment: My guess is that either the author had a function there that was removed and they forgot to take out the brackets, or they think JS has a block-level scope.

Comment: The only reasons for those braces I can find are bad reasons...

Comment: Maybe whoever wrote that thought that JavaScript has block scope (which it doesn't) and was trying to reduce the scope of `s_account`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat that's not even a JavaScript object. That's just a block.

Comment: It probably helps them to collapse a bunch of variable declarations.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I think rocket was referring to the "or a json object

var attributes"

Comment: @dystroy: Yep, that's what I was referring to.

Comment: alright alright! JavaScript object :)

Comment: Could be just to isolate the variable declaration, looks weird though.  If that's one of the first things, maybe it's declaring a local object to hold local variables, to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Comment: @Seano666: But, JavaScript doesn't have block scope.  So the variable is declared in whatever scope the block is in.  (The code runs as if the block wasn't there)

Comment: In a more classical language with a stricter syntax like C++, such blocks can be used to limit an automatic variable life length, i.E it gets destroy when leaving the block. In javaScript it has no effect.

Comment: Thanks for all the discussion guys... as someone who's come from a design background, not development per se its really interesting to hear

Comment: `let` and `const` introduced in JavaScript v6 do have block scope, so this now does have more utility, e.g. inside the `case`s of a `switch`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why there are curly braces with no text before them or after them? What does it do / what is the point of it?

There is no significant point to them in Javascript.  It will act exactly the same as if the code was just

```
var  s_account="blog";
```

Speculation

In other languages which have block scope, this might restrict the scope of the variable, but since JS doesn't have that feature (for better or worse), braces without a control structure or function are essentially meaningless and ignored.

Most likely this code was left over from a deleted function or if statement however.  It definitely is not a pattern to be copied.

Comment: Now that we have block scope with let and const this could be useful in some scenarios

Comment: The code will act exactly the same.  This doesn't mean it's pointless.  To follow your logic, are line breaks pointless?  Are half of all semicolons in JS pointless?  Are comments pointless?  As people pointed out below, IDE's and many text editors allow you to collapse block statements.  They allow you to segment your code with more than just whitespace.  -1 for non-answer when there are valid answers.

Answer (score 17):

It's a block and completely pointless unless you label it:

```js
block: {
    var s_account="blog";
    console.log("executed");
    break block;
    console.log("not executed");
}
```

Comment: You can use `break`s like that?

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes, just run it through your console. Or add conditional break and see the alert execute when the condition is false.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I was curious about that until now too, but [yes you can](http://es5.github.io/#x12.8)

Comment: I've never used labels.  So, does it act like a "goto"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes, it gotos to the end of the labeled block

Comment: This was really helpful. What else can we do with blocks? I'm guessing we can jump around them as if they were mini switches or mini functions?

Comment: Super helpful. I ran across a similar looking labelled block which had a `break` statement after successful initialization of some variable. Your answer provided explanation for my curious mind.

Comment: It's not completely pointless if you use `let` or `const` to scope a variable to the block (probably not available at the time of the original post).

Answer (score 13):

The only logical reason to do something like this, in my mind, is as an organizational technique.

```
function banana(){
    // private members
    {
        var foo = "foo",
            bar = "bar",
            baz = "baz";

        function bux(){
            console.log("bux");
        }
    }

    // public members

    this.fin = "fin";
    this.fang = "fang";
    this.foom = "foom";

    this.shamalamadingdong = function(){
        bux();
    };
}
```

Also, most IDEs will allow you to collapse that "private members" block and get it out of your way.

Comment: Hey, that's a really good point especially about the collapsable side inside an IDE.  Its weird, its only a single variable in there though... my other thought is maybe its generated code.

Comment: The number of variables shouldn't really matter when using a convention. If you are ever going to use the convention, you should *always* use it.

Answer (score 12):

That's a block statement. Block statements have multiple purposes, none of which are being used by that code (other than perhaps to group the content together [as Shmiddty suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18130388/157247)). (In fact, I'd say in that code they're counter-productive, because for the many people coming to JavaScript from languages where all variable declarations are block-scoped, they create the impression that the variable is scoped to the block, which it isn't.)

Uses it can have:

### Scoping `let`, `const`, and `class`

If that code were using `let`, `const`, or `class`, the block would scope the resulting identifier because `let`, `const`, and `class` **are** block-scoped in JavaScript. So this outputs `"bar"`:

```js
{
    var foo = "bar";
}

console.log(foo);
```

but this throws a `ReferenceError` because `foo` is scoped to the block:

```js
{
    let foo = "bar";
}

console.log(foo);
```

### Providing a block to break

As [Esailija points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18130264/157247), if it were labelled and using `break`, the break would exit the block early.

### Grouping statements attached to a flow-control statement

The most common use of a block statement is to group together the statements attached to a flow-control statement like `if` and `for`. In this fairly typical `if`:

```
if (something) {
    doThis();
    doThat();
}
```

...the `{}` aren't *part of* the `if` (you can write `if` without using `{}`), they're a block statement *attached to* the `if`.

Comment: I think your `let foo = "bar";` example still logs `bar`.

Comment: @Djave - Try it, it's a runnable snippet. :-) The only way it will log `"bar"` is if the JavaScript engine has a broken implementation of `let`. I don't know of any that are broken in that way. (IE9 has an outdated implementation of `let` that fails important use cases related to `for` loops, but IE9 doesn't allow `let` in blocks, so it doesn't log `"bar"` above. [I wasn't sure, so I tried it. :-) ])

Comment: Ahhh... I see what I did... I copied and pasted them into the terminal... so the second `console.log` logged the `var` *facepalm*

Comment: @Djave - LOL! Yup, that explains it. :-D

Answer (score 7):

It's called a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).  It lets you group expressions.  It's normally used with control structures like `if` and `while`, but can also be used on its own.

Since JavaScript doesn't have block scope, the code runs in the same scope (as if the `{}` weren't there).

Example:

```
{
    var s_account="blog";
}

console.log(s_account);
```

That works fine.

Comment: Only it doesn't allow function declarations inside…

Comment: Read the *Note* on function declarations as [statements](http://es5.github.io/#x12)… Try to call it in FF above the declaration and it'll fail.

Comment: @RocketHazmat "JavaScript doesn't have block scope" - in version <=5 and except for `with` statements and `try/catch`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick addition.
In some IDE like Visual Code, putting Curly Braces will actually create a visual block with a 'drop-down' arrow, allowing you to completely hide a portion of code with just a click.
It helps with code organization.
I'm using it when creating HTML element with a lot of CSS.
Since it does not affect code execution, this is very useful.