# Why is `function() {{` legal in JS?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I recently saw some JS of the form:

```
function f(x) {{ return x + 1; }}
```

To my amazement, this is syntactically legal and works fine. At first I thought it was C-style anonymous scopes, but it does not introduce a new scope:

```
function f(x) {{ var y = x + 1; } return y;} // no error
```

Why does JS accept these superfluous brackets? How are they interpreted/what do they mean?

Comment: That's a misunderstanding of `var`-declared variable scope.

Comment: `{ ... }` is a block. JS does _NOT_ have block-level scoping. So basically it does nothing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130025/javascript-curly-braces-with-no-function-or-json

Comment: Whoever wrote it with double braces must have been smoking something, cause it does nothing at all, even if it's valid

Comment: Also see the MDN: [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv: Technically, when you commented in May that JavaScript didn't have block-level scoping, you were correct. The final ES2015 spec adding block-level scoping (`let`, `const`, `class`) wasn't released until June. Still, though, the writing was etched into the wall even a couple of years ago... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: completely agree. JS, as implemented right now by some browsers - and "emulated" with transpilers like Babel - , does have block level scoping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{}` simply denotes a block, or "group", of code. Unless paired with something like an `if` statement it simply doesn't do anything useful. Scope for `var` is determined by `function`s in Javascript, not blocks.

The new `let` in ES6 scopes to blocks.