# Wrapping an entire JS code block within {} in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What's the point of wrapping an entire code block within two curly braces? For example within .js file:

```
{    
const firstVar;

class firstClass {}

class secondClass {}    
}
```

Is this to create a blockscope and keep the global name space clean? Is it comparable to wrapping an entire javascript module within a self invoking function for example?

Take a look at this JS file for example;

https://github.com/codrops/PageFlipLayout/blob/master/js/demo.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript curly braces with no function or json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130025/javascript-curly-braces-with-no-function-or-json)

Comment: related: [Will const and let make the IIFE pattern unnecessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33534485/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is very similar to the old practice of creating an IIFE to isolate your variables from the global scope.

Since `const` and `let` are *block* scoped, as opposed to *lexical* (or function) scoped, you don't need to create an entire function and call it. Just wrapping it in a block is enough.

```
{
  const foo = 42;
  console.log(foo); // 42
}
console.log(foo); // ReferenceError
```

It's worth noting that this practice is still less used (and less powerful) than an IIFE, since an IIFE also protects you from leaking `var`s and `function` declarations, which a block would not. Although the common use-case today is to use a module, which would implicitly prevent leaking variables and objects into the global scope.

Only `let`, `const` and `class` are block-scoped.

Comment: Thank you, needed to confirm

Comment: Function declarations are block-scoped as well (although they might also leak to the surrounding scope in sloppy mode).